# Integration of Admanager in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, double-click-advertising

we are currently building a new Angular 4 Web Application. For that we want to integrate Google Addmanager aka Doubleclick for Publisher. This is a tool from Google to spread your own Adds on your own platform. Works pretty easy and gives out 2 HTML Codes in the end which then have to be integrated in the website.

In the  of the page:

```
 <script async='async' src='https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'></script>
<script>
  var googletag = googletag || {};
  googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
</script>

<script>
  googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    googletag.defineSlot('/sfjdxysdef', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-12345678-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    googletag.enableServices();
  });
</script>
```

In the page.component.html:

```
<div id='div-gpt-ad-12345657879-0' style='height:250px; width:300px;'>
<script>
googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-12345657879-0'); });
</script>
</div>
```

I now integrated them. One in the index.html (for the header content) and one in the HTML component of my page where I want to display the add. For some reason it is not working like this in the moment. As the  container where the add should go is just white. Can anybody assist me here? Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any errors on the console?

Comment: Blocked a frame with origin "https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net" from accessing a frame with origin "https://***.de". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.